# A geodesic which stop minimizing must self intersect?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a **complete*** Riemannian manifold.
Let $\gamma$ be a geodesic which stops minimizing at some point.

Is it true that $\gamma$ must be periodic or self-intersect? (in a transversal way)

I suspect it's false, but I could not find an example.

---

*For non complete manifolds it's certainly false (Look at $\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \{p\}$)

Comment: A non-circular helix on a cylinder is not globally minimizing, but does not self-intersect. (This is, of course, John Ma's example lifted to a covering.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M =\{ (e^{it}, e^{is}) : s, t\in \mathbb R\}$ be the torus with Euclidean metric. Let 
$$\gamma (t) = (e^{it}, e^{i\sqrt 2 t}).$$
This geodesic never intersect itself. Note also that every geodesics on a compact manifold must stops minimizing at some points.

Comment: You mean the flat torus, right?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}$ @AsafShachar

Comment: Thanks. Actually I knew about the dense curve on the Torus, but somehow I didn't think of it as a geodeisc. Do you have an example on a non-compact manifold?

Comment: You can take the above example with the product with $\mathbb R$. @AsafShachar